# fitting an inverse proportional function

Tags: python, scipy

I want to fit the function `f(x) = b + a / x` to my data set. For that I found scipy `leastsquares` from optimize were suitable.

My code is as follows:

```
x = np.asarray(range(20,401,20))
```

`y` is distances that I calculated, but is an array of length 20, here is just random numbers for example

```
y = np.random.rand(20)
```

Initial guesses of the params a and b:

```
params = np.array([1,1])
```

Function to minimize

```
def funcinv(x):
    return params[0]/x+params[1]

res = least_squares(funinv, params, args=(x, y))
```

Error given:

```
 return np.atleast_1d(fun(x, *args, **kwargs))
```

> TypeError: funinv() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

How can I fit my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a little of clarity. There are two related problems:

1. Minimizing a function
2. Fitting model to data

To fit a model to observed data is to find such parameters of a model which *minimize* some sort of *error* between model data and observed data.

`least_squares` method just minimizes a following function with respect to `x` (`x` can be a vector).

> F(x) = 0.5 * sum(rho(f_i(x)**2), i = 0, ..., m - 1)

(`rho` is a loss function and default is `rho(x) = x` so don't mind it for now)

`least_squares(func, x0)` expects that call to `func(x)` will return a vector `[a1, a2, a3, ...]` for which a sum of squares will be computed: `S = 0.5 * (a1^2 + a2^2 + a3^2 + ...)`.

`least_squares` will tweak `x0` to minimize `S`.

Thus, in order to use it to fit model to data, one must construct a function of error between a model and actual data - *residuals* and then minimize that *residuals* function. In your case you can write it as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

x = np.asarray(range(20,401,20))
y = np.random.rand(20)
params = np.array([1,1])

def funcinv(x, a, b):
    return b + a/x

def residuals(params, x, data):
    # evaluates function given vector of params [a, b]
    # and return residuals: (observed_data - model_data)
    a, b = params
    func_eval = funcinv(x, a, b)
    return (data - func_eval)

res = least_squares(residuals, params, args=(x, y))
```

This gives a result:
`print(res)`

```
... 
message: '`gtol` termination condition is satisfied.'
    nfev: 4
    njev: 4   optimality: 5.6774618339971994e-10
    status: 1
    success: True
    x: array([ 6.89518618,  0.37118815])
```

However, as a residuals function pretty much the same all the time (`res = observed_data - model_data`), there is a shortcut in `scipy.optimize` called `curve_fit`: `curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, x0)`. `curve_fit` builds residuals function automatically and you can simply write:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = np.asarray(range(20,401,20))
y = np.random.rand(20)
params = np.array([1,1])

def funcinv(x, a, b):
    return b + a/x

res = curve_fit(funcinv, x, y, params)
print(res)  #  ... array([ 6.89518618,  0.37118815]), ...
```